# How to document "Retry-After" HTTP-Date format in OpenAPI?

Tags: swagger, openapi

Trying to document a response header of `Retry-After` in HTTP-Date format in OpenAPI ([as described here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.3) and [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.37)).

Also here you can find the syntax which is in use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Date

**Syntax**:

```
Date: <day-name>, <day> <month> <year> <hour>:<minute>:<second> GMT
```

My question is what is the best way to describe this header and which format is the correct one when using OpenAPI 3?

`date`/`date-time`/`http-date`?

Answer (score 0):

OpenAPI and JSON Schema do not have a built-in `format` for dates in this format. However, `format` is an open-valued keyword so you can specify any value you like, such as `format: http-date` or even

```yaml
format: <day-name>, <day> <month> <year> <hour>:<minute>:<second> GMT
```

Tools that don't recognize the given `format` value will ignore it and use just the `type`.

That said, I suggest that you use `type: string` without `format` and optionally provide an `example` value. Or you can make it `oneOf` of string and integer to reflect the alternative format `Retry-After: 120`. (However, a simple `type: string` also works in this case.)

Example using `type: string`:

```yaml
responses:
  '429':
    description: Rate limit exceeded
    headers:
      Retry-After:
        description: Indicates how long the client should wait before making a follow-up request. 
        schema:
          type: string
          # example: 'Wed, 21 Oct 2022 07:28:00 GMT'

        # optionally add examples for both date and delay-seconds
        examples:
          http-date:
            value: 'Wed, 21 Oct 2022 07:28:00 GMT'
          delay-seconds:
            value: '120'
```

Example using `type: string` + `type: integer`:

```yaml
        schema:
          oneOf:
            - type: string
              example: 'Wed, 21 Oct 2022 07:28:00 GMT'
              description: A date after which to retry.
            - type: integer
              minimum: 0
              example: 120
              description: The seconds to delay after the response is received.
```